# Making a responsive grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Okay, I'm trying to make a responsive grid, but it is a bit more complicated than that. It has to be able to:

- Resize, be responsive
- The grid should have as many elements in a row as it can fit, **and**
- There have to to be at least two elements in a row
- The minimum page size is 320px
- **A element should maintain aspect ratio**

Here's a starter: http://codepen.io/loredonut/pen/KJDAE

A CSS-only solution would be great. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use xy.css here : http://xycss.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now used `<img>`s and made them responsive, here's a demo: http://codepen.io/loredonut/pen/FGneA

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of grids you can use.

Since it looks like you are going for mobile screens, too, have a look at

[960 Grid](http://jeromeetienne.github.io/jquery-mobile-960/)
[1140 Grid](http://www.1140px.com/)

Most of the grids will give you x number of responsive columns, which on smaller screen sizes collapse to **100% width**.

Now if you really want to get fancy have a look at `CSS-column-count` and `CSS-colum-gap` - found here [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/), ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count)). Although you need some fallback for IE6-9, this should allow you to make colums with different row height - as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMbtk/55/).

Comment: Sadly, this is not really appropiate for use of image display, or am I getting the concept wrong?

Comment: @Florija: I found it looking for an image display grid - see the example [here](http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/). So it should work - at least it does for cats ;-) Otherwise, please give a little more info how the images should behave.

Answer (score 1):

There are many grid frameworks that may fit your purpose:

- [**`Foundation`**](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [**`Semantic Grid`**](http://semantic.gs/)
- [**`Golden Grid System`**](http://goldengridsystem.com/)

There are also:

- [CSS Grid](http://cssgrid.net/) (not fluid)
- [320 and Up](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/) (not fluid)
- [Columnal](http://www.columnal.com/) (not fluid)
- [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) (not fluid)
- [SimpleGrid](http://simplegrid.info/) (not fluid)
- [Less Framework](http://lessframework.com/) (not fluid)
- [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) (non-semantic classes)
- [Breakpoints.js](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/breakpoints/) (only breakpoints, too similar to media queries)
- [Adaptive images](http://adaptive-images.com/)> (only images)
- [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/) (only text)
- [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) (old)

[See this related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741934/responsive-grid-layout-framework)

My personal favorite is Foundation by the way. It is very actively developed and is based on Compass/Sass.

Answer (score 0):

Try using twitter bootstrap.. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

and u can also combine it with isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ and get MAGIC effect :)

this also could save u hours in integrating isotope with bootstrap: http://mpezzi.github.io/bootstrap_isotope/